# Posición relativa de un Button en diferentes mecanismos o tamaños de pantalla

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema con relación a la localización relativa de un Button al ejecutarlo en diferentes tamaños de pantalla. He hecho una breve aplicación para mostrarlo. El resultado es que el Button, con relación a un punto rojo, se comporta según lo deseado cuando se trata del ancho (coordinada x). Sin embargo, no sé por qué el mismo Button se desliza progresivamente hacia abajo respecto al punto rojo (coordinada y) según ejecuto la aplicación en tamaños de pantalla menores. Elijo el tamaño de imagen correcto para cada mecanismo xlarge, small… y el ancho y el alto son relativos porque también los elijo de las medidas relativas de cada pantalla:
    rel_btn.width = 4*width/100;
    rel_btn.height = 7*height/100;

Les muestro el código y la pantalla resultante de la aplicación en una xlarge, a partir de la cual el recuadro azul va a irse deslizando hacia abajo. ¿Podría alguien ayudarme?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //width and height of the screen
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (windowManager != null) {
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    }
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.test); // id del XML
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rel_btn.width = 4*width/100; rel_btn.height = 7*height/100;
        // x, y of the BUTTON
        rel_btn.leftMargin = 15*width/100; rel_btn.topMargin = 66*height/100;
        Button btnTag = new Button(this);
        btnTag.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);
        btnTag.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        btnTag.setId(0); // writes the ID
        btnTag.setOnClickListener(prueba);
        layout.addView(btnTag);
}

private View.OnClickListener prueba = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //width of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        Button button = (Button) view;
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(Math.round((float) (0.6*width/100)), Color.BLUE);
        drawable.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    }
};
```

}
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Comment: No esta muy claro tu problema. Trata de especificar el resultado que esperas y el resultado que obtienes en varias imagenes. Segun entiendo, lo que quieres es posicionar un boton en una misma posicion? lo que no esta claro es, donde especificas en tu codigo que el boton va a estar en esa posicion? te falta algun detalle como agregar tu axml?. Otra cosa, el recuadro solo aparece al darle click al boton? puedes aclarar tu pregunta editandola.

Comment: Perdona si no me expliqué bien. El resultado que espero es que el Button (rectángulo azul que debería aparecer siempre y solo al pulsar sobre el punto) aparezca en los diferentes tamaños de pantalla siempre rodeando el punto (como en la xlarge). O, como dices, posicionar un botón en una misma posición. Sin embargo, se desliza progresivamente hacia abajo como puede verse en la imagen que he vuelto a editar.  En mi código, el botón va a estar en esta posición:
   // x, y of the BUTTON
   rel_btn.leftMargin = 15*width/100; rel_btn.topMargin = 66*height/100;

Comment: prueba a cambiar windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); por getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); y quita el if de antes

Comment: Probé, pero el problema continúa. Gracias.

Comment: Revisa la actualizacion del codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es encerrar tu vista con un Rectangulo (tipo contenedor). No debes hacer **hardcoding de tamaños y coordenadas**, sino que debes establecer un valor relativo. El valor relativo, debe ser representado en porcentajes.

Por ejemplo, si quieres que aparezca una vista en una **posicion (x, y)** de un contenedor el cual "visualmente" aprecias una medida, si te fijas ese view en el contenedor representa un valor porcentual respecto a la pantalla que ves. Por lo tanto, al establecer un valor fijo, no siempre representara la misma posicion en una pantalla, a menos que dichas coordenadas representen un porcentaje respecto al tamaño que genere.

Dicho esto, tu solución es la siguiente:

Debes utilizar un contenedor de la vista y no un boton, si lo que quieres representar es una vista dentro de un contenedor (El punto rojo dentro del rectangulo).

Ejemplo de **activity_main.axml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Si te fijas, aquí defino un `Button` (que representara el **Ovalo o punto rojo**), con un tamaño cuadrado de **25dp x 25dp** (El valor debe representar un tamaño en dp o densidad por pixeles, para que sea un valor relativo a la densidad de la pantalla). A su vez, defino un contenedor que representara el **rectángulo azul** (es un `FrameLayout`, es mas común como contenedor, ya que te permite colocar la vista en una posición relativa). La propiedad `layout_gravity` del `Button`, colocara el `Button` en el centro del contenedor, ya que si no lo establezco asi, se colocara en la **posicion (0, 0)** de su padre y se vera en la esquina superior izquierda del rectángulo. El `layout_margin` jugara un papel muy importante aquí, mas adelante la explicación.

Tu código quedara mas o menos así, para poder establecer la `posicion (x, y)` de la vista, que sea la misma para todas las resoluciones o tamaños de pantalla.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private Button btn;
    private FrameLayout flContainer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //width and height of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        // Esto crea el punto rojo
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
        btn.setBackground(drawable);

        // Cuando se haga click en el boton, se pintara el rectangulo azul
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        flContainer = findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
        // Posicionamos el contenedor (rectangulo azul), que tiene al ovalo como hijo
        flContainer.setX(width * .25f); // Posicion del contenedor estara al 25% del width de cualquier pantalla, respecto a la posicion 0 de X
        flContainer.setY(height * .75f); // Posicion del contenedor estara al 75% del height de cualquier pantalla, respecto a la posicion 0 de Y

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        // El rectangulo azul se le aplica al FrameLayout porque es quien contiene al ovalo o punto rojo
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(convertDpToPx(this, 5), Color.BLUE);
        drawable.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        flContainer.setBackground(drawable);
    }

    private int convertDpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics);
    }
}
```

La funcion convertDpToPx te convierte en valor a Dp, ya que no puedes establecer un tamaño en Dp en el axml y otro en pixeles programaticamente, ya que no establecerias una relacion correcta respecto a los tamaños. Ahora bien, si te fijas, el stroke es definido con 5dp:

```
drawable.setStroke(convertDpToPx(this, 5), Color.BLUE);
```

Esto es, porque, si el contenedor `FrameLayout` contiene un `Button` de `25dp` al ser `wrap_content` el limite del boton, quedara justamente en el limite del `FrameLayout`. Por eso se establece un `layout_margin`, para despegar el boton, de los limites del `FrameLayout`. Al establecer en el `Button` como `layout_margin` 10dp, no puedo establecer un **stroke** de 10dp, porque el width de la linea azul, quedaría pegada exactamente en el limite del ovalo, por eso al ponerle 5dp que es la mitad del margen, quedaria o se veria reflejado un poco despegado del ovalo.

Un ejemplo mas claro, asume que los circulos son del mismo tamaño:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*A la izquierda el ejemplo de 10dp de margin y 5dp de stroke. A la derecha 10dp de margin y 10dp de stroke*.

### Actualizacion

Para centrar la vista como dije anteriormente, no basta con hacer `.setX` y `.setY` al 50% tanto del width como el height. Hay que restarle las dimensiones de width y height correspondientes de la vista dibujada. Si nos fijamos en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asumamos que el punto x, y esta en el centro. Sin embargo la vista no esta en el centro, porque es dibujada desde el punto hacia la derecha y desde el punto hacia abajo. Por tanto para poder colocar la vista en el punto x, y ya seteado. Necesitamos restar la mitad del width de la vista y la mitad del height.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que el codigo quedaria asi:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLayoutChangeListener{
    private Button btn;
    private FrameLayout flContainer;
    private int height, width;
    private float xPos = 0, yPos = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //width and height of the screen
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if (windowManager != null) {
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        }
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels;

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
        drawable.setColor(Color.RED);
        btn.setBackground(drawable);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);

        flContainer = findViewById(R.id.flContainer);
        flContainer.addOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //width of the screen

        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(convertDpToPx(this, 5), Color.BLUE);
        drawable.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        flContainer.setBackground(drawable);
    }

    public static int convertDpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
        if(xPos == 0)
            xPos = (width * .5f) - (v.getMeasuredWidth() * .5f);
        if(yPos == 0)
            yPos = (height * .5f) - (v.getMeasuredHeight() * .5f);
        v.setX(xPos);
        v.setY(yPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfecto trabajo que a su vez demuestra que eres un gran conocedor del tema. Sin embargo, hay algo que al parecer no se cumple. Cuando dices:

Comment: // Posicionamos el contenedor (rectángulo azul), que tiene al ovalo como hijo
flContainer.setX(width * .25f); // Posición del contenedor estará al 25% del width de cualquier pantalla, respecto a la posición 0 de X
flContainer.setY(height * .75f); // Posición del contenedor estará al 75% del height de cualquier pantalla, respecto a la posición 0 de Y

Comment: Veo que efectivamente el recuadro azul rodea perfectamente el punto rojo pero sin embargo ambos se van deslizando hacia abajo hasta incluso desaparecer en una pantalla small. Yo quiero aplicarlo todo después a una aplicación en la que por ejemplo aparezcan en el fondo los puntos de las capitales en un mapa de Europa. ¿Estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Andrespengineer, tenías razón, mis pantallas estaban en modo landscape. De todos modos, no veo que la proporción se cumpla en todas. Se va deslizando el punto hacia abajo hasta tal punto que en small, aunque aparece, lo hace casi escondiéndose. Mientras no solucione esa proporción, no puedo hacer nada en mi programa deseado (el de Europa...) ¿Se te ocurre algo?

Comment: No es exactamente ni lo uno ni lo otro, pero se parecería más a lo segundo: se trata de tener ya los puntos definidos en un mapa de fondo (tal como comencé mi problema) y después, al pulsar en cada uno de ellos, aparezca el cuadrado azul para indicar capital, parte del cuerpo… Ya tengo el programa realizado, y los porcentajes calculados para la xlarge, el problema es que esas proporciones o porcentajes no se cumplen en los distintos dispositivos o tamaños de pantalla. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Me preguntas que cómo creé el punto. Como te dije, es una imagen de fondo.

Comment: No me importaría crear los puntos con tu sistema para mi aplicación, siempre que consiga proporciones o porcentajes equivalentes en todos los dispositivos.

Comment: De acuerdo, allí nos vemos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78024/discussion-between-f-alvarado-and-andrespengineer).

Comment: He estado esperando allí todo el fin de semana hasta hoy. Al no conseguir tu respuesta, he estado investigando y al parecer no tengo la suficiente reputación para intervenir en el chat. ¿Habría alguna solución, pues tenía puestas en ti mis esperanzas?

Comment: Quizás la única solución de momento sea seguir expresando aquí mi problema, que es de posición: el punto aparece en posiciones diferentes en las distintas resoluciones. Incluso tratando de colocarlo en el centro, que suponía ser con ...50f tanto para width como para height, aparece en otro lugar.